# Mahatmya of the five shiva temples of Ceylon

Tags: shiva, puranas, temple, shaivism

In Ceylon, there are 5 main shiva shrines collectively called the pancheswaram. They are [Naguleswaram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naguleswaram_temple), [Thiruketheeswaram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketheeswaram_temple), [Munneswaram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munneswaram_temple), [Thondeswaram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenavaram_temple) and
[Koneswaram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koneswaram_Temple).

[image]

It seems these places are among the 275 Paadal petra sthalams mentioned in the Shaiva Tirumurai.

**Question:**
Would like to know the mahatmya of these individual places (independent of any relation to the Ramayana) and whether any of them are among the 68 shiva kshetras.

Would also like the verses mentioning these sthalams in the Tirumurai.

---

Note: While answering it would be nice if one is able to find the Dakshina Kailasa Mahatmya of the Skanda Purāṇa as mentioned in Koneswaram’s linked page and [here](http://repository.kln.ac.lk/bitstream/handle/123456789/19749/87.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)